# Extract Flickr photo ID from static image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

The goal of this is to automatically add an attribution link to an image used in a blog post. I've got a  **[demo set up here](http://dev.brianbennett.org/image-credit)** which manually uses `flickr.photos.getInfo` to build the attribution URL on the image.

To do that, I took the photo ID from `background-image` in the CSS and created the API call. What I'd like to do is automatically pull the photo ID (**3990985751** for this example) from the `background-image` url to create the API call on each post.

**CSS**

```
.featured {
background-image:url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2613/3990985751_7ca0769f15_b.jpg');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="featured">
<body>
    <div class="featured">
      <div id="featured-credit">
        <p id="credits"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery/JS**

```
// Builds the URL to link in the image credit
      function jsonFlickrApi (response) {
        $("#credits").html('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+response.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+response.photo.id+'/" target="blank">'+response.photo.title._content+"</a>");
      }

      // removes the CSS formatting for the featured image background URL
      function extractUrl(input) {
        return input.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
      }

    /* After all the scripts are loaded, send the featured photo to the Flickr API to get the JSON data */
    <script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=APIKEYHERE&photo_id=3990985751&format=json&jsoncallback=?"></script>
```

I researched a bunch on SO and other sites, and the other solutions I found were all using the profile URL, whereas I need to use the static source URL. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented above that the `$.ajax` call wasn't working for me, but I was able to solve it using jQuery's `$.getJSON` method. JS only below:

```
// removes the CSS formatting for the featured image background URL
      function extractUrl(input) {
        return input.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
      };

      //Set a variable to hold the extracted URL & pass the string to the next function
      bg = extractUrl($(".featured").css("background-image"))
      extractPhotoId();

      // This *really* ugly Regex pulls out the photo ID from the extracted URL and saves it in a variable
      function extractPhotoId() {
        photoId = bg.replace(/(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})\/(\d{3,5})\/(\d{7,15})(?:(?!ab).)*/ig, '$3');
      }

      // Constructed API url to use with the JSON request
      var apiUrl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=c8c95356e465b8d7398ff2847152740e&photo_id=" + photoId + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

      // Call the Flickr API URL and apply the data to the source credit div
      $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data){
          $("#credits").html('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/" target="blank">'+data.photo.title._content+"</a>");
        });
```

Here's a working **[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/qAJCB)** if you want to play with the image source in the CSS to try it out. You may need to refresh the page after you change the source URL in `background-image` to get it to update the credit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried do a ajax call to the flicker?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data:{
        method: 'flickr.photos.getInfo',
        api_key: 'c8c95356e465b8d7398ff2847152740e',
        format: 'json',
        photo_id: yourPhotoID,
    },
    success: function(data){
        //data is the response from flickr
    }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work and wasn't able to figure out why the `success` code wasn't firing, even though the API was called successfully. I ended up using the `$.getJSON` method instead.

Comment: Sorry, it was missing the parameter contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8".